# Limit Combobox input based on other control on same form

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, combobox, where-clause

I have a database in access for which I made some forms, which is going pretty well.

I only have one small issue I am running into.

I have this form on which I have several comboboxes, which get their Row source from another table. That is working fine.

But for combobox B I wanted the options limited/filtered based on the selection in combobox A. So I filled the following in the row source of combobox B:

```
SELECT JOBS.Numbers
FROM JOBS
WHERE CITY = Me.CITY
```

So there is another combobox on the same before where the `CITY` is picked.

Now when open combobox B it asks me to fill in the city manually and then it filters/limits the options in the way I want. However, I want this to happen automatically based on the selection in combobox A (on the same form).

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I find this feature very useful. For example I have a form where project managers select there name from a combobox(A) then in the next box(B) select their project. B uses the criteria from the first box to only list their projects.
Specifically the project table I pull the list from has an owner field. I use the name entered into A as criteria on the Owner to pull just their projects.

On the combobox query build I input the Owner criteria like this. The query runs then with whatever data is entered into boxA. 
Forms![Main]![cboOwner]

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I tried it, but not succeed (yet)

Where should I insert the: boxA. Forms![Main]![cboOwner]. I tried it on several places but did not succeed? I for example tried putting it the beforeupdate and onclick event of combobox B

Comment: Just wanted to let you that I succeeded in doing this, thanks to your comment.

Comment: Sorry for not responding, I was on vacation. Please mark the answer as accepted if that is what helped you succeed.

Answer (score 0):

On the first combo box "After Update" event add `Me.ComboboxB.Requery`. That will make combo box B refresh its contents based on the current value of combo box A every time A's value is changed.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I tried it, but not succeed (yet)

I tried putting the following as a VBA code in the afterupdate box of the first box

Private Sub comboboxA_AfterUpdate()
Me.comboboxA.Requery
End Sub

But nothing happens, not even a error, that is the strange thing. Could it be that I need to link the comboboxes first or something like that?

Comment: Just wanted to let you that I succeeded in doing this, thanks to your comment.